# UnsatisfiedLinkError with JNI program

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I work with JNI, i followed all those thing from https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html#zz-2.1

I run the java program,it is showing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hello in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at HelloJNI.<clinit>(HelloJNI.java:3)
```

I don't know how to solve this?

Comment: Please post the java program in which you are facing this issue and also let us know what exactly you are trying, so that we can try to help.

Comment: public class HelloJNI {
   static {
      System.loadLibrary("hello"); // Load native library at runtime
                                   // hello.dll (Windows) or libhello.so (Unixes)
   }

   // Declare a native method sayHello() that receives nothing and returns void
   private native void sayHello();

   // Test Driver
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new HelloJNI().sayHello();  // invoke the native method
   }
}

Comment: I believe that you can edit your original post to include the code. It would be easier to read.

Comment: Also, can you say which OS this is running on, and how you execute the program.

Comment: i am using Ubuntu OS